# How to get current logged in user id and upload that id as data in Android using Mysql Database

Tags: java, android, mysql

I want to get current user logged in user id which is stored in shared preference and then insert that id as data or information with photo to another table in Mysql Database.

I have already tried many methods to get current logged in user id and then upload it as data with photo. I try to find errors in debugger but debugger doesn't show any expected errors.

This My Java Code

```
public void uploadMultipart() {
        //getting name for the image

        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(filePath);

        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            CA_SIGNUP_GTST user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(UploadDOC_Activity.this).getUser();

            int id = user.getId();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(UploadDOC_Activity.this, uploadId, UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path,"adhar_card") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("expid", String.valueOf(id))
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    //handling the image chooser activity result
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                iv_adhar.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //method to get the file path from uri
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }


    //Requesting permission
    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
        }
        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }


    //This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

            //If permission is granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Displaying a toast
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that the will upload but when i run the app it doesn't show any error and user id and image also is not insert in database.